# scikit learn ExtraTreesClassifier prediction gives different execution time with Pandas DataFarme vs datatale Frame vs Numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, optimization, scikit-learn

I am using scikit learn ExtraTreesClassifier.

```
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier

def __init__(self):
    self.ExTrCl = ExtraTreesClassifier()
```

**The prediction gives different execution time with Pandas DataFarme vs datatale Frame vs Numpy array !!**

At the beginning, I generate a numpy 2d array based on the test dataset, `generateTestPart(testDataSet, list_motifs_used_in_train)`.

I use three methods to make the prediction, using 1) pandas datafarme :

```
def test_groupe_score_pd(self, test_matrix)
    start_time_0 = time.time()
    dftest = pd.DataFrame(test_matrix,columns=self.list_motifs)
    end_time = time.time()
    print(" time creating DataFrame = ", end_time-start_time_0)

    start_time = time.time()
    result = self.ExTrCl.predict(dftest)
    end_time = time.time()

    print(" Time pred only = ",end_time-start_time," s")
    print(" Time create + pred = ",end_time-start_time_0," s")
```

2. using datatable:

```
    def test_groupe_score_dt(self, test_matrix):
        start_0_time = time.time()
        dt_dftest = dt.Frame(np.array(test_matrix),names=self.list_motifs)
        end_time = time.time()
    
        print(" time create Fram dt = ",end_time-start_0_time)
    
        start_time = time.time()
        result = self.ExTrCl.predict(dt_dftest)
        end_time = time.time()
    
        print(" Time pred only = ",end_time-start_time," s")
        print(" Time pred + create = ",end_time-start_0_time," s")
```

3. using directly numpy:

```
    def test_groupe_score_numpy(self, test_matrix):
        start_0_time = time.time()
        start_time = time.time()
        result = self.ExTrCl.predict(test_matrix)
        end_time = time.time()
        
        print(" Time pred only = ",end_time-start_time," s")
```

The result , by using matrix of size > 500 Mo are in the following table :
[image]

It is very clear that for the prediction only, using pandas gives the best results, but we have to consider the creation of the dataframe also, hence, using directly numpy seems to be the best choice.

**The Question is: why there is such a difference in the prediction time? Using pandas vs datatable vs numpy**

Thank you for help.